# how to load code on php just one time

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

this is a part of code php page, and i just want to load the code for one time so, when i load the page (full of code page (include the code bellow)) if the code bellow have loaded one time then the code bellow can't loaded.

I have code like this :

```
    $notif = $userData['pemberitahuan'];

        $userId = $userData['id'];
        $ket = 'unread';

        $update_data = array(
            'pemberitahuan' => $ket
        );


        $this->db->where('id', $userId);
        $query = $this->db->update('user', $update_data);

        return ($query === true) ? true : false;


?>
```

So how i can load this code for one time? and doesn't loaded when the page of full code is load or refresh??

Comment: a session could help you

Comment: can you give me example @RafaelShkembi

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Answer (score 0):

A session variable can help you achive this

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION["loaded"] != "yes"){
     $_SESSION["loaded"] = "yes";
     $notif = $userData['pemberitahuan'];
     $userId = $userData['id'];
     $ket = 'unread';

     $update_data = array(
        'pemberitahuan' => $ket
     );


     $this->db->where('id', $userId);
     $query = $this->db->update('user', $update_data);

     return ($query === true) ? true : false;
}
```

Starting we check if the session variable is true. If the session isn't true then our condition is met and execute the code. When we start ececuting the block code we set the $_SESSION variable to "true". If the page refresh-es this part of code won't execute anymore.

Comment: `"true"` won't work since that isn't a boolean true, it's a string, as shown in your return.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's only a example. in our case is only a string i know. Technicly the script above would work

Comment: *"It's only a example"* - So why did you post an example that will fail?

Comment: @Fred-ii- this example will not fail.

Comment: waitt, i'm sorry, this code is doesn't work, if i try to your code, the code doesn't loaded at all, i want to load one time. @RafaelShkembi

Comment: ^ See, I told you. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php --- `var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)` so `var_dump((bool) "true");   // bool(false)` would be its counter equivalent, See also http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @Firm in some part of your code you need to reasign the value of the variable. When you consider that the code should run again the assing e different value that "true" to the variable

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have changed the value.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you give me an example so you can give me example will not fail

Comment: @Fred-ii- The example code was fine before the edit. $_SESSION['loaded'] was set as a string type, not bool. It would have evaluated properly. Using the word "true" does not cast the variable as boolean. So your quoting of the manual and example test make absolutely no sense here.

Comment: http://ideone.com/2LU68R Showing that this answer is valid. I don't think it's the best solution in this case, so I can't upvote. A better solution would be checking the database to see if the value is already set to unread. But I don't trust the code sample enough to hazard an attempt at an example.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i got error because A session had already been started, and when i use condition for season like this : if(!isset($_SESSION)) the code will be loaded when another season is loaded.